# node terminal doesnt accept my path for app.js (error unexpected idetifier)

Tags: node.js

when use cd to give a path to node (like  C:\Users\1\Desktop\path) for run my app it dont accept it and  give this error

`cd C:\Users\1\Desktop\path
^

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

tried all format used backslash forward slash for format in path but it always show err

Comment: the angle bracket is under the C in the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try
`C:\\Users\\1\\Desktop\\path`

Comment: tried it before no difference still get the same error ty btw